# The following JQuery and Javascript does not work correctly in Internet Explorer 6 onwards

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, html, replace

Any idea why the following code will not continually update in IE6 & 8 but works perfectly fine in Chrome and FF.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        window.setInterval(function () {

            $('div').each(function (index, item) {

                var vm = $(item).text();
                var env = "some url (cant show)";

                $.ajax(env, {
                    URL: env,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (data) {                          
                        var style = $(data).filter('div');
                    $(item).replaceWith(style);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(item).css('background', '#f00');
                    }
                });
            });
        }, 10000);
});
```

The divs will change once, then never again. Whereas, in Chrome and FF the divs change every 10 seconds as they are meant too.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your script like (didn't test it)...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    window.setInterval(function () {

        $('div').each(function (index, item) {

            var vm = $(item).text();
            var env = "some url (cant show);

            $.ajax(env, {

                URL: env,

                type: "GET",

                cache:"false", //NOTICE FALSE!!

                dataType: "html",

                success: function (data) {


                    var style = $(data).filter('div');
                    $(item).replaceWith(style);

                },

                error: function () {



                    $(item).css('background', '#f00');

                }

            });
        });

    }, 10000);

});`
```

Comment: I also must note I did cache: false, - excluding the double quotations.

Comment: Hmm try to add   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  above your ajax function. Maybe it will do the trick. If not than don't know what else you can do:(

Comment: Tried this also - Still no joy!

Comment: Well if you can try to change 'GET' into 'POST' ?